# Extract 'dt' class from 'div' using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract date from the HTML div class using beautiful soup. structure of HTML is as follows

```
<div class="message-attribution-main">
<a href="/site/threads/my-overall-experience-with-ford.5489/post-155992" class="u-concealed" rel="nofollow">
<time class="u-dt" dir="auto" datetime="2021-04-17T11:16:57-0700" data-time="1618683417" data-date-string="Apr 17, 2021" data-time-string="11:16 AM" title="Apr 17, 2021 at 11:16 AM">Saturday at 11:16 AM</time>
</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract 'data-date-string' from the above HTML tag. My code is as follows

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(f"https://www.macheforum.com/site/threads/my-overall-experience-with-ford.5489/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

date = []

for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"message-attribution-main"}):
            for x in item.find('time',attrs={"class":"u-dt"}):
                print(x)
```

The above code just gives me output as 'Saturday at 11:16 AM' how can I extract the exact date from the above HTML. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `["data-date-string"]` to access the tag attribute:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    f"https://www.macheforum.com/site/threads/my-overall-experience-with-ford.5489/"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

date = []

for item in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "message-attribution-main"}):
    for x in item.findAll("time", attrs={"class": "u-dt"}):  # <--- use .findAll
        print(x["data-date-string"])  # <--- use ["data-date-string"]
```

Prints:

```
Apr 17, 2021
Apr 17, 2021
Apr 17, 2021
Apr 17, 2021
Apr 19, 2021
Apr 19, 2021
```